# Recommended grid systems or layouts for large display and responsive designs

Tags: website-design, workflow, website-templates, responsive-design

I've been working with **960 layout** for years – but was wondering if there are other **grid systems** that are strongly supported by the design and development community and also have blank or starter pages to work with.

Comment: http://www.onedesigns.com/freebies/a-1140px-16-columns-css-grid-system  was retired

Comment: A quick google search will show you plenty of options.

Comment: See this post for more frameworks: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/16410/7520

Answer (score 4):

I'd say [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) is probably one of the favorites.

It has a nice [grid system](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) that utilizes 12 columns, making for a 940px wide container without responsive features enabled. With the responsive CSS file added, the grid adapts to be 724px and 1170px wide depending on your viewport. Below 767px viewports, the columns become fluid and stack vertically:

[image]

It also allows for column offset and nesting.

Comment: Foundation4  is also pretty advanced. When you design what are you designing on for pixel dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

See this post for more frameworks: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/16410/7520

Also check out this [site](http://usablica.github.io/front-end-frameworks/compare.html) for many options. Personally I use a customized version of [Base](http://matthewhartman.github.io/base/docs/index.html). It is very light weight and doesn't have all the 'bells and whistles' if you're someone who likes the DIY option.